# HTML Slider element?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, html, canvas

I'm coding an app (temporarily up [here](http://wafflegaze.com/cool)), and I want to make its parameters modifiable. I feel the best way to do this would be with your standard GUI slider elements (a la [this](http://mthamilton.ucolick.org/techdocs/instruments/AO/images/hartmannSliders.jpg), but not so ugly). I just noticed that the DOM doesn't provide these, however...

What's the best way to introduce sliders to a webpage? Is there a standard library that everybody uses? Should I just roll my own? Or should is there a different element I can use? Should I embed them in the canvas element somehow?

Comment: `input type="range"` in HTML5. Browser support isn't there yet, though.

Comment: range and some other input types are supported in Chrome and Safari: examples on http://simon.html5.org/presentations/html5-geekmeet.en

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) does [support this](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/).

If you're already using jQuery, it would be easy to learn.

Answer (score 33):

There is a slider control in HTML5, it's done with <input type="range" … />.

Check browser support here: http://caniuse.com/input-range

Comment: 3 and a half years later -- this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is probably a jQuery library for this as well, but this MooTools library is one that I have used before and had no complaints:

[MooTools Slider](http://mootools.net/demos/?demo=Slider)

Answer (score 0):

I have used the one in YUI3. It is still in beta but it provides a lot of great features and skins. http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/slider/